# What is the meaning of "of"?

Tags: prepositions

> abdominous : [archaic] (**of** a person) having a large belly, fat.

What is the meaning of "**of**"?

Comment: in this context, it means roughly "about". "of a person" here means "when used in the context of describing a person"

Comment: ... said or written **of** a person - it is said of Joe Smith that he is abdominous. As the dictionary notes, it is an archaic word.

Comment: Try **adipose**, it's nicer. Dictionaries: said or written **of a person** who x. It means about.

Answer (score 1):

Abstractly, *X of Y* overall most often means that Y is a bigger or primary thing and X is a part or a "branch" somehow.

That "bigger or primary thing" can be a category, type, or definition - something that would provide the answer to "What is X"?

More specifically, when used in this manner, it's equivalent to saying "when regarding an X"

> abdominous : [archaic] (of a person) having a large belly, fat.

means:

> abdominous : [archaic] (when regarding a person) having a large belly, fat.

Comment: And which of these, if any, relates to the particular question?

Comment: ----- The first?

Comment: So what is it exactly that is in the category "a person"? To be clear - while all your senses are indeed meanings of "of", I don't believe any of them is relevant, because the original is not "X or Y" it is "**be said** of Y" which is a predicate not a NP.

Comment: After meditating on this for some time, I updated and hopefully this is a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

abdominous: [archaic] (of a person) having a large belly, fat.

"of" there means: **said of a person** having a large belly, fat.

It's a dictionary phrase that is often shortened.